# Read database from SQL Server - WP8 Application in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, windows-phone-8

I have an database in my MS SQL Server and I want to create a WP8 App which can log in and can read over sql query or update the database.
In c# there is it easy to connect to a SQL Server, but in WP8 its more complicated. Can anybody help me? I want to connect to a database over a username and a password and I want to read and edit the database.

Answer (score 1):

you can  develop a web service talking to your database, deploy it to IIS on your Azure instance and then consume it from your Windows 8 application (by adding a web reference to your web service in Visual Studio)